# How to Install Safari 9 on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, safari, mac-appstore, software-update

I don't want to move to El Capitain yet but now some sites are complaining about my safari version (8). I search the internet and found references that Safari 9 was release for Yosemite and Mavericks:

- http://www.macworld.com/article/2987211/software-web/apple-releases-safari-9-for-yosemite.html
- http://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/30/apple-releases-safari-9-for-yosemite-users/

However, I can't find it in the Mac App Store. It is not available as update.

How can I download Safari 9 on my Yosemite?

Comment: Safari 8 is an integral part of OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). Safari 9 is now an integral part of OS X 10.11 (El Capitan). If you are using 10.10 Yosemite then I believe you can upgrade Safari from the App Store. If it is no longer available from the App Store to Yosemite users, then you should decide whether you will upgrade to El Capitan. There may yet be a very few third-party apps or drivers which are not yet compatible with El Capitan. Almost everyone who runs Yosemite will be able to run El Capitan, but check first.  *Please record an answer your own question showing how you solved your issue.*

Answer (score 2):

I found that Safari 9.0 for Yosemite is indeed available, but first you have to upgrade to the most recent Yosemite version 10.10.5

In my case, I had 10.10.4 and the update for Safari was not showing up in the App Store. I wanted to update all at once but first you have to do the system update.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated to 10.10.5 (tried using the combo update, and then the standalone 10.10.5 update).  When going to the app store, safari 9+ is not available for 10.10.5 on two test machines; you gotta update to el capitain.  I contacted apple education, and they confirmed this for me.

All security patches applied, through 2015, 2016 (ending at 2016-007).

ARGH!